# How to copy Navigation Title to UILabel?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

Hey I am new to iPhone app development. I want to copy navigation bar title to another UILabel of same view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UINavigationController` .. you can simply do

```
  Yourlabel.text = self.title;
```

Comment: You mean: Yourlabel.text = self.title

Comment: Yeah i tried the code, but it isn't working..Thanx 4 ur help btw.

Comment: Is there any other way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `myLabel.text = self.navigationItem.title;`